# Is AdView in Android contain a WebView inside it ?

Tags: android, webview, admob, adview

I have been working on implementing my own AdView custom view that does similar functionality to Google's AdView.

I looked at the inheritance tree of AdView it seems that it inherits from  ViewGroup and then from View.

Does anyone know if AdView contains a Webview that displays HTML based ads ? or AdView only supports images and text?

If its not a WebView can anyone think of any concern of using a Webview as a container for my ad banner?

Comment: I am going to assume that an AdView does indeed contain a WebView, as you need to activate internet access permissions to use AdView, so it is safe to assume it does. If not, it is something that descends from WebView.

Comment: See: http://doubleclickpublishers.blogspot.com/2012/04/mraid-support-in-dfp-simplifying-in-app.html

Comment: I think your are building your sdk, and in this case the developer will use web view to display ads, is it good (security wise) to give developer web view which contains html code to connect to your ads system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admob AdView uses a WebView.

Comment: how did you figure that out?

Comment: 5 years of playing with it :-) the logcat often includes lots of snippets that clearly show it is using a WebView, HTML and JS.